# Querying Parent/Child value using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I compare values in a Parent/Child relationship? These are my models

SystemOne [id, code, date, status];

SystemTwo [id, code, date, status];

```
class SystemOne
{
    public function systemTwo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SystemTwo::class, 'code', 'code');
    }
}
class SystemTwo
{
    public function systemOne()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SystemOne::class, 'code', 'code');
    }
}
```

Using Eloquent, how can I get Model where child's 'status' is different to parent's 'status' ?

Comment: Can you give more information about your situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your use case here, but just as an idea on how you can get the `systemTwo` from `systemOne` only if their status is different you can use something like this

```
SystemOne::with(['systemTwo' => function($query) {
     $query->where('status', '!=', 'TABLE_NAME.status');
}]);
```

replace the `TABLE_NAME` with system two table name.